laravel application loads white blank screen on cpanel
i am currently deploying laravel application in cpanel , everythin is fine except when i launch the application via url http://wellresponsive.com it loads white blank screen only , how ever when i press F12 key i found the warning  This page is in Quirks Mode. Page layout may be impacted. For Standards Mode use “<!DOCTYPE html>”. moreover in error_log file in the app's root folder i found the following error
[02-Apr-2024 08:50:40 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::handleRequest does not exist. in public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php:112
Stack trace:
#0  Illuminate\Foundation\Application->__call('handleRequest', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home3/wellresp/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php on line 112

I've seen many relating questions and answers on this site but none of them solved my problem
what is causing such errors? how can it be solved ? any solution will be appreciated

It seems that this error is a sign of not having all of vendor dependencies in place:
please try following commands
composer dump-autoload
composer install --no-scripts

check site for errors and if all is ok you can go with
composer update
